# Configuring oracle database as airflow metadata backend db does not create airflow tables when deployed from docker

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, database-metadata

I am running a proof of concept to connect airflow and oracle database to store airflow metadata. From the documentation (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#database-uri) I have seen that mostly PostgreSQL, MySQL and MSSQL are supported with PorsgreSQL being the most preferable. However, since SQLAlchemy supports Oracle connections I configured the airflow docker image to initiliaze with an oracle db.

First of all, I would like to clarify that I am using Docker on a linux Ubuntu 20.4 LTS version and everything is deployed there.

I will start with the docker-compose.yml file which is similar to the one from the official airflow documentation (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.1/docker-compose.yaml):

```yaml
version: '3.8'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  #image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.6.1-python3.8}
  build: .
  env_file: .env
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: oracle+cx_oracle://NIKOS:Nikos_123@oracle-db:1521/?service_name=ORCLPDB1
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'False'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session'
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    oracle-db:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  oracle-db:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:21.3.0.0
    container_name: oracle-db-airflow
    environment:
      ORACLE_SID: ORCLCDB
      ORACLE_PDB: ORCLPDB1
      ORACLE_PWD: Oracle_123
      #ORACLE_EDITION: standard
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    volumes:
      - oracle-data:/opt/oracle/oradata
      - oracle-backup:/opt/oracle/backup
      - ./create_oracle_user.sql:/create_oracle_user.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "/opt/oracle/checkDBStatus.sh"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 2
    restart: unless-stopped

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    env_file:
      - .env
    user: root
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        mkdir -p /opt/oracle
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y unzip
        unzip /opt/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /opt/oracle/
        apt-get install -y libaio1
        sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_10 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
        ldconfig
        ls /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_10 | grep "libclntsh.so"
        /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /entrypoint version
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru.zip:/opt/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru.zip
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_10

volumes:
  oracle-data:
    external: false
    name: oracla_store
  oracle-backup:
    external: false
    name: oracla_backup

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    name: network_airflow_poc
```

The oracle-db service is an official oracle database taken from the [container.registry of Oracle](https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:4:100027427929263:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:9,9,Oracle%20Database%20Enterprise%20Edition,Oracle%20Database%20Enterprise%20Edition,1,0&cs=3bexrG5ZDn8duhrKEyV3hvGKFHt5TrQo9IXve4mghfl_dk_dJIL46eIL1gwSUj4LnIRG7sULHIbELr-X8w5qTQw) . The database is healthy and running. I can check the connection to the database along with the user credentials with Oracle SQL Developer free app. Also the user `NIKOS` is valid and has the following privileges `GRANT CONNECT, CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW TO NIKOS;`

My problem is found when the service `airflow-init` is executed. As you will notice I have added some extra bash commands under this service in the docker-compose file. This is because `cx_Oracle` package and the Oracle Instant Client are not installed by default. Thus, I had to do the following steps:

Step 1: Create a `Dockerfile` and a `requirements.txt` with the following configurations respectively ([documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.1/howto/docker-compose/index.html#special-case-adding-dependencies-via-requirements-txt-file)):

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.6.1-python3.8
ADD requirements.txt . 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```
sqlalchemy==1.4.48
cx_Oracle==8.3.0
```

And rebuild the docker airflow image by uncommenting the build argument (`build: .`) of the docker service.

Step 2: Install Oracle Instant Client inside the airflow container. Thus following the steps of the official [documentation_1](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html), [documentation_2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lacli/install-instant-client-using-zip.html#GUID-D3DCB4FB-D3CA-4C25-BE48-3A1FB5A22E84) I managed to overcome the following error

> DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library

However, the whole solution fails to complete due to the following log:

[image]

full error log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e2sAI2K7ixV7nScJvOr8BOqu_H23_81J/view?usp=sharing)

The error basically says that the table `log`, which I assume is an `airflow metadata` table is not found found. Because is never created.

The odd thing is that when I execute the whole docker-compose file with a `PostgreSQL` database as metadata backend and checking the results in PGAdmin, I can clearly see the initialized tables like `log` and others.

[image]

Thus, my question is how can I overcome the current issue I am facing in the error logs? Even though Airflow has a valid SQLAlchemy Connection string and the necessary dependency libraries installed, it cannot initiate properly its metadata tables in the oracle db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem. Based on the full stack trace the problem was under the `db.py` file, located at */home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/*

In this file the function `check()` was called before starting to build the metadata tables. The `check` function actually checks whether the database is alive. The following command was executed when the function was called.

`session.execute("SELECT 1 AS IS_ALIVE")`

The SQL statement does not follow the Oracle SQL systax. Thus, I changed the command to

`session.execute("SELECT 1 AS IS_ALIVE FROM DUAL;")`

That was the solution to the problem I posted.